# Spurious point is being added in the end C3 charts

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, d3.js, c3.js

I'm using C3 charts library to draw charts. I send data to the chart using two arrays, which are 'timeArray' and 'dataArray', one for the X-Axis and the other one for Y-Axis respectively. This simple logic was working fine.

Later I had to implement a change such that I had to take average of every three elements of an array and then make a new array and then plot the graph using averaged values.

I started facing a problem that a spurious point was being plotted on the graph. Whenever this error occurs, only one spurious point is added in the end. I've checked the arrays that are used to plot the graph, they do not have that spurious point. When I take the average of every three elements, I face this problem almost every time, however when I take average of 500 or 1000 points I face this error only sometimes.

As you can see in the code I have already tried removing the last point of the final array since the spurious point that was being added was always the last point in the chart. I've also tried changing the graph type, it did not help.

```
socket.on('get-avg-graph', function(data) {

    // dataPoints = Points for Y-Axis
    // mili = Points for X-Axis

    var dataPoints = data.dataPoints;
    var mili = data.mili;

    var sumX = 0;
    var sumY = 0;

    var avgXGraph = 0;
    var avgYGraph = 0;

    var avgXArray = [];
    var avgYArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < dataPoints.length - 999; i++) {

        for (var j = i; j < i + 999; j++) {
            sumX = sumX + mili[j];
            sumY = sumY + dataPoints[j];
        }

        if (sumY !== 0) {

            avgXGraph = ( sumX / 1000 );
            avgXArray.push(avgXGraph);

            avgYGraph = ( sumY / 1000 );
            avgYArray.push(avgYGraph);

            sumX = 0;
            sumY = 0;

            avgXGraph = 0;
            avgYGraph = 0;
        }         

    }

    io.emit('get-avg-graph-response', avgXArray, avgYArray);
});

socket.on('get-avg-graph-response', function(avgXArray, avgYArray) {

        plot_X_axis = [];
        plot_Y_axis = [];

        drawChart();

        avgXArray.splice( -1, 1);
        avgYArray.splice( -1, 1);

        plot_X_axis.push.apply(plot_X_axis, avgXArray);
        plot_Y_axis.push.apply(plot_Y_axis, avgYArray);
        drawChart();
});

function drawChart() {
        var graphTitle = $("#test_type_show").val();

        dataArray = [];
        dataArray[0] = "PRESSURE";
        dataArray.push.apply(dataArray, plot_Y_axis);

        timeArray = [];
        timeArray[0] = "TIME";
        timeArray.push.apply(timeArray, plot_X_axis);

        if (chart==null) {
            chart = c3.generate({
                bindto: '#chart1',
                title: {
                    text: graphTitle
                },
                data: {
                    x: 'TIME',
                    columns: [
                     timeArray,
                     dataArray
                    ],
                type: 'spline'
                },
                axis: { 
                    x: {show:false},
                    y: {show: true}
                },
                grid: {
                    x: {
                        show: true
                    },
                    y: {
                        show: true
                    }
                },
                point: {
                    show: false
                }
            });
        } else {
            chart.load({
                x: 'TIME',
                columns: [
                 timeArray,
                 dataArray
                ],
            type: 'spline'
            });
        }
        chart.internal.xAxis.g.attr('transform', "translate(0," + chart.internal.y(0) + ")");
        chart.internal.yAxis.g.attr('transform', "translate(" + chart.internal.x(0) + ", 0)"); 

}
```

I expect the output of the code to be the actual graph without any spurious data added anywhere.